# How to change IP using fiddler before passing to server?

Tags: ip, fiddler

Please find the scenario below:

I want to know from which country my application is getting called, which can be easily detected by the IP Ranges.

But for testing purpose I need to get the IP's from different countries. I know few features of Fiddler like auto responder.

But I want to know that how can I update the response before sending it to server.. by using Fiddler or any known tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can't (generally) change the outbound IP with Fiddler or another tool. You'll have to find an open-proxy in the target locale and use that to bounce your traffic. A *few* servers will respect an X-Forwarded-For HTTP header that specifies the target IP of your choice, but most won't.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this script under FiddlerScript tag to add XFF header for a given site.
    sXFFip = "1.2.3.4"

```
if (sXFFip.length > 0) {
        if (oSession.uriContains(".xyz.com")) { 
            oSession.oRequest.headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", sXFFip); 
        }

    }
```

This should append xff header with the one you declare.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
   if (oSession.HostnameIs("subdomain.example.com")){
   oSession.bypassGateway = true;                   // Prevent this request from going through an upstream proxy
   oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "128.123.133.123";  // DNS name or IP address of target server
   }
```

For more details check this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse)

Comment: The OP is asking to change the IP address of the machine making the request, not the IP address of the machine it is requesting from (which could be done with a HOST entry).